# Apache2 - disable cache for internet explorer

Tags: apache, internet-explorer

I've tried to find this on documentation, search egines, and so on... no solution found but maybe you have one.

I cannot use NGinx for some reason.

I have to use Apache2 (on debian).

I have to disable javascript cache (set an exprire header) only for Internet Explorer ( IE < v9 if possible)

BrowserMatch options doesn't give any possibility as far as I know. Is anybody can give me some idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I foudn my own solution that can help some others users...

The idea is to set envvar and use "header" directives that can check this var:

```
BrowserMatch "MSIE 9.0"  ie9
<FilesMatch \.js>
    # for javascripts, if ie9, set cache and expires
    header set Cache-Control no-cache env=ie9
    header set Expires "Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT" env=ie9
</FilesMatch>
```

That seems to be ok for our configuration, if someone has other ideas.